# Remove automatically rows based on a condition - Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I have data with duplicates rows and I'm looking for a way to remove them automatically. I created a column indicating rows occurrences and I'd like to delete all rows in my table corresponding to the condition: `[Rank] != 1`. 
I have this:

```
|ColA | ColB | Rank |
|-----|------|------|
| a1  |  b1  |  1   |
| a2  |  b2  |  1   |
| a1  |  b1  |  2   |
| a3  |  b3  |  1   |
| a1  |  b1  |  3   |
| a3  |  b3  |  2   |
```

And would like to obtain this:

```
|ColA | ColB | Rank|
|-----|------|-----|
| a1  |  b1  |  1  |
| a2  |  b2  |  1  |
| a3  |  b3  |  1  |
```

The data source being dynamic, I wonder if there is a way to use a scheduler to perform this task...

Comment: Can you just write a TERR script that duplicates the datatable but filters out `[Rank] != 1`? Then source that datatable for everything.